# How to link a user with taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

Im trying to assign users to a taxonomy term during sign up with drupal7 and profile2.

There used to be a profile taxonomy for drupal 6 but its not ported to 7 yet.

Is there a way of doing this with reference/entity reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is

http://drupal.org/project/entityreference

I just created a new field for the user account select entity reference then you can choose any entity within drupal to reference. (ie so you can select a term/content/anything)